# Adding “Zebra Stripes” to every second visible row Automatically when AutoFilter changes

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have a report of around 250 rows (varies +/- 15 rows, columns A – J).  To make the report easier-on-the-eye for end users, I format every second row with Zebra Stripes.  The problem is that whenever a filter is applied to the data, the zebra stripes (rows) sometimes bunch together which defeats the purpose of having them at all.

What I would like to do is have the zebra stripes appear on every second visible row after the filter is changed - and I know such code already exists on this site – but I furthermore  want to have this happen automatically without the need to trigger any code.

My current macro works fine as far as adding the formatting – but doesn’t achieve the ideal objective stated above.  Any guidance is appreciated.

```
Sub AddZebraStripes()

Dim c As Range, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheet1.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2:J" & LastRow)
If c.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
    c.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1: c.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.15
End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just make it into a table? They behave like that natively if you use a striped format.

Comment: I agree with @Rory. This is the most simple way to achieve what you want. If you still want VBA then there is a workaround that you will have to employ as there is no event which traps the Autofilter change. You need to create a cell with a formula and use the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event as shown [HERE](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/capture-filter-change-event-in-excel-using-vba.htm) to trap Autofilter change. And in that code follow these steps **1.** Remove existing colors **2.** Get the visible range using `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` **3.** Apply the colors.

Comment: You could also do it with conditional formatting as long as one of the columns always has data in it.

Comment: @Rory - GOOD IDEA!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Rory and Siddharth that using a table as the simplest option.  However, if you’re stuck on using a VBA approach then this is how I would do it:

You can trigger the code automatically by using a Worksheet_Calculate() event handler – based on a calculation of a formula on the sheet.

**First step** is to add the following formula to cell `K1` (for example based on your description of your data) on your sheet:  `=SUBTOTAL(3,$A:$A)`.  This particular SUBTOTAL (3,) = COUNTA().  Whenever the filter changes, it will recalculate – even if the same number of rows are visible in Col `A`.  You can hide Col `K` if you like – it won’t affect the code execution.

**Step Two** – add the following Worksheet_Calculate() event handler to the Sheet1 module

The following code will run the macro `ZebraStripes` whenever it detects a calculation in cell `K1` on Sheet1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Set Target = Me.Range("K1")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K1")) Is Nothing Then
       ZebraStripes
    End If
End Sub
```

**Step Three** – add the following code to a standard module

```
Option Explicit
Sub ZebraStripes()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

ws.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    i = i + 1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Set r = Range(c, c.Offset(0, 9))
            r.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1: r.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.15
        End If
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

If you follow the 3 steps above precisely, you should achieve your ideal objective of every second row shaded – automatically whenever there’s a change to the filter on the sheet.  Looking at all the steps/code, I think you might be better off with a Table :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also easily use conditional formatting if you have a column which will always have data in it.

> The references are in the formula are pointed to the first cell in the data column of choice

*Please note the absolute vs non-absolute cell reference in the formula.* Set the format for true, then depending how you want the banding you can reverse "TRUE" and "FALSE" in the formula

```
=IF(MOD(SUBTOTAL(103,$A$2:$A2),2)=0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

*UPDATE*

To allow for blank values in data column:

```
=IF(MOD(SUBTOTAL(103,$A$2:$A2)+COUNTBLANK($A$2:$A2),2)=0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```